# Python: How do I wrap function calls, not the functions themselves?

Tags: python, for-loop, function-calls

For example, I've got functions, `funcA()`, `funcB()`, `funcC()`. I'd like to call each of these functions, but after each one, perform a series of other functions, like `func1()`, `func2()`, `func3()`, `func4()`.

I know that I could:

```
funcA()
func1()
func2()
func3()
func4()
funcB()
....
```

Or that I could:

```
def funcCombined():
    func1()
    func2()
    func3()
    func4()

funcA()
funcCombined()
funcB()
funcCombined()
...
```

But is there a better way? I tried putting them in a list, like:

```
funcs = [funcA(), funcB(), funcC()]

for func in funcs:
    x = func
    func1()
    func2()
    func3()
    func4()
```

But it seems to be executing all of the functions in the list and *then* executing them in the for loop.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your functions take different arguments, store them in a dictionary or a 2nd list

```
funcs = {
    funcA: (1, 2, 3), 
    funcB: ({'a' : 1}, [1, 2, 3]),
    funcC: None
}

for func, args in funcs.items(): 
     if args is None:
         func() 
     else:
         func(*args)
```

Comment: Perfect! I forgot to mention they all have different arguments.

Answer (score 5):

Don't call the functions before you want to

```
funcs = [funcA, funcB, funcC]

for func in funcs:
    func()
```

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. Unfortunately, my functions all take different arguments. I'm guessing I should do what @Timo recommended. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can store the functions in the list not the returned value from their call - functions are first class objects in Python -  and call them in the loop, calling the group of functions after each call:

```
funcs = (funcA, funcB, funcC)

for func in funcs:
    func()
    funcCombined()
```

Comment: You do not want to call the function in the list `funcs`.  Treat them as variables similar to how @Jurgy is doing

Comment: @SciGuyMcQ Brainfart on that. Typo fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct when you think that each function is being called when you first put them in the list. This is because `funcA()` calls `funcA`. However, you can refer to `funcA` by omitting the parentheses --- this refers to fhe function itself.

You can make your list of function (without calling them), loop over them, call them, and call the other set of functions like

```
funcs = [funcA, funcB, funcC]
for func in funcs:
    func()
    funcCombined()
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you store a list of function objects rather than results, it can be done in a one-liner;

```
map(lambda func: func(), funcs)
```

Note: In Python 3.x, map returns a generator, but you can get around the lazy-evaluation by casting to a list;

```
list(map(lambda func: func(), funcs))
```

If you want to pass arguements, see [itertools.starmap](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap)